# how can I incorporate ui-bootstrap modal in my angular 1.5 app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

My basic app is basically a bunch of flowers (images of flowers) and you can add the flowers to a flower pot..

I'm trying to incorporate modals into the app, so that if I click on a flower photo, a modal will show up with some information about the flower (name, color).

Here's how I am thinking of it:

`Click a flower -> model.showDetails(flower) -> display modal template with that flower's name and color`

So, in my template, I have the following inside of the repeater:

```
<img ng-src="{{flower.image}}" ng-click="model.showDetails(flower)">
```

In my `component.js`, I have the following method, and this is where I'm having trouble :(

```
model.showDetails = function(flower) {
  var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: "flower-details/flower-details.html",
  })
}
```

How can I pass the flower name and color into the markup in `flower-details.html`?

```
<h1>Flower Information</h1>
<a ng-click="model.dismiss()">X</a>
<div>
  <p>{{model.flower_name}}</p>
  <p>{{model.flower_color}}</p>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the data to modal from resolve of modal popup. Thereafter you need to inject that `flower` resolve into the controller factory function by which you can receive value of current flower. And then while using variable on HTML you could prefix them with `modalScope.` to reference them correctly.

**Code**

```
model.showDetails = function(flower) {
  var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: "flower-details/flower-details.html",
    resolve: {
       flower: function(){
          return flower; //resolve function returning flower.
       }
    },
    controllerAs: 'modalScope',
    controller: function(flower){
       var modalScope = this;
       modalScope.flower = flower; //got the flower from resolve.
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: thanks Pankaj.  Can you, if you don't mind too much, please explain how the resolve property works?  Thank you

Comment: @user1354934 in resolve are mainly used in a modal to pass something(data) to the modal control, so that it can process that, when you inject inside a controller that value gets available to controller.. sometimes resolve could be promise & you can take use of to show some loading till it gets completed..

Comment: Thank you Pankaj!  May I ask one more question please, I am new to angular and curious.  How come when writing components, the $scope is not used, but in this case it was used?  I'm wondering from the phone cat tutorial, they used `var model = this;`